# Load data while Scrolling with condition query base

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Load-data-while-Scrolling-Page-down-with-jQuery-AJAX-and-ASPNet.aspx

Above link is having code example to load data on demand(Infinite scroll) is it possible to use join query.

I don't want to create this SQL PROCEDURE is it possible with query. because this procedure has DECLARE the. it's quite difficult to change the SQL PROCEDURE each time.

Answer (score 0):

> it will be easy to manage store procedure in place of hard coding
>   because if anything will require to modify then you can change Store
>   procedure from server, Otherwise if you have done hard code in
>   application then you have to publish complete application to change
>   anything.

Comment: I want to add data from column sub table then how to do. I didn't understand the method to make the inner join in this and how we can use  the condition in this?

Comment: it is very simple, for joins you have to understand Joins of sql and then according to requirement you have to use that.. as i can see your provided link there is SELECT * FROM #Results so if you require to add data in search then make join in that search with row number..